# Fix a div to the bottom while scrolling with skrollr

Tags: css-position, skrollr

I'm trying to use Skrollr to fix an element to the bottom of the viewport, if the bottom of the element hits the viewport bottom. This part is fine.

The problem is, after - lets say 1000px - of scrolling, i want to continue the scrolling, while i change the above mentioned fixed element to static again.

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="height-placeholder" data-anchor-target="#fixed-element" data-0-bottom="display:none;" data--0-bottom="display:block;"></div>
<div id="fixed-element" data-0="@class:;" data-bottom="@class:stuck;" data-1000="@class:;">Fixed at the bottom for a while</div>
<div class="content">
    Regular content...<br>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkccg8x5/2/

So my idea was to create a placeholder above the fixed element and when the fixed element is stuck to the bottom, i simply add this element, so when i unstuck the fixed element, it would continue to scroll normal without any jump.

The problem with this solution is that i defined a fixed height for the placeholder, and this way it will only work correctly at a certain viewport height. Makes things more complicated, that every element on the site has a fluid height, so i need a solution that will work in every resolution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a 1000px tall container and when the bottom of the container is hitting the bottom of the viewport, i change the fixed element to absolute.

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div id="height-placeholder" data-0="@class:;" data-bottom="@class:unstuck;">
    <div id="fixed-element" data-0="@class:;" data-bottom="@class:stuck;">Fixed at the bottom for a while</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Regular content...<br>
</div>
```

Here is the demo, works fine with any height:

http://jsfiddle.net/bkccg8x5/3/